# Efficiency of Async Task In Adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a HomeScreenActivity which contains a ViewPager and it contains 3 pages. Now I want to download some content through Async Task to show it inside Page 1.

Flow of code:

> HomeActivity - where I set the viewpager Adapter.
>
> HomeViewPagerAdapter
>
> CustomAsyncTask
>
> CustomAsyncTaskInterface - to notify the download of the content.

Is calling AsyncTask from the adapter a good approach? Or should I do it from the HomeActivity?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing in the AsyncTask

Comment: I think, AsyncTask is used only for downloading content.

Comment: Sure, but what content? HTML, JSON, images, other media files?

Comment: 21:02 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3D0cWyNno4

Comment: I am just getting JSON content and it doesn't contain images or any other media file expect basic data types.

Answer (score 1):

If the AsyncTask should build the data list for the adapter, then it should be ran from the Activity/Fragment containing the adapter. You'll set or notify the adapter within onPostExecute.

If the AsyncTask is downloading data *per adapter item*, then it should be part of the adapter class, called in `getView`, and you update the `getItem(position)` element from onPostExecute.

---

For example, say you have a list of data that contains an image URL, but the adapter only needs to display the title of the item, not immediately display the image. This first AsyncTask to get the data list for all items goes in the Activity

You only need to show the image when you click on an item, or fetch additional details about something. In that case, the secondary AsyncTask that gets more data, specifically for a particular item, is in the adapter.

Comment: Can you give the reason for doing all this inside activity rather than inside the adapter?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "all this". I would recommend not doing more network requests than necessary to display the data that you want to show at a particular time

Comment: @adbhi_bond: Adapters show data you already have.  Activity gathers data from potentially multiple sources.  It's about separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be setting the adapter on the method onPostExecute of the AsyncTask, because there you will know that the AsyncTask has finished executing.